# How to call specific method without writing several if statements?

Tags: python-3.x, class, dictionary

I have a series of methods I would like to call from an Azure function in a Function App - get, update, rebuild, and append. While it is simple enough to make four if statements for this, it seems like an inelegant way to do it. Instead of having a series of if statements, I thought that I could use a `dict[keyword]:function()` type of operation to parse out the function I need, and then call it by seeking the key that corresponds to that function:

```
# hashable dict of keywords and functions
    etl_func_dict=dict()
    etl_func_dict["Update"]=UpdateFunc()
    etl_func_dict["Append"]=AppendFunc()
    etl_func_dict["Rebuild"]=RebuildFunc()


    etl_func_dict[name]
```

where `name` is a parameter passed along a query string.
When I build this dictionary, the output is as expected, but checking the logs shows that the functions are executed when the dictionary is built as well:

```
Executing 'Functions.recreate-etl-dict' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=681bf979-464a-4f33-9fd8-bcbc2b30232d)
[10/10/2019 4:58:10 PM]  INFO: Received FunctionInvocationRequest, request ID: c529a334-197e-44f2-a3a1-6dc7a9c875e0, function ID: c4bf936a-c34a-4f97-b353-f86cd66ff230, invocation ID: 681bf979-464a-4f33-9fd8-bcbc2b30232d
[10/10/2019 4:58:10 PM]  INFO: Successfully processed FunctionInvocationRequest, request ID: c529a334-197e-44f2-a3a1-6dc7a9c875e0, function ID: c4bf936a-c34a-4f97-b353-f86cd66ff230, invocation ID: 681bf979-464a-4f33-9fd8-bcbc2b30232d
[10/10/2019 4:58:10 PM] UpdateFunc Running...
[10/10/2019 4:58:10 PM] AppendFunc Running...
[10/10/2019 4:58:10 PM] RebuildFunc Running...
```

Looking around in some documentation of other modules (like `requests`) leads me to believe that I need two classes here - one class that stores the methods I'm creating, and another class that creates an instance of the first class based on passed input. However, as someone new to Python, I am unsure of how to approach this, or even if this is the correct way to approach this.

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    def UpdateFunc(self):
        logging.info("UpdateFunc Running...")
        stringy="Update"
        return stringy
    def AppendFunc(self):
        logging.info("AppendFunc Running...")
        stringy="Append"
        return stringy
    def RecreateFunc(self):
        logging.info("RecreateFunc Running...")
        stringy="Recreate"
        return stringy
    # hashable dict of keywords and functions
    etl_func_dict=dict()
    etl_func_dict["Update"]=UpdateFunc()
    etl_func_dict["Append"]=AppendFunc()
    etl_func_dict["Recreate"]=RecreateFunc()

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    try:
        s = etl_func_dict[name]
        return func.HttpResponse(s,
                                 status_code=200)
    except:
        if not name:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                 "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
                 status_code=400
            )
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("Name did not match a valid key. Expected values are: {}".format(list(etl_func_dict.keys())))

    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body.",
             status_code=400
        )
```

If the dictionary had initialized without running the functions, then this would not require a question to be asked. With the dictionary of functions, I get the expected output, it just also runs all of the functions when the dictionary is created, and I don't know how to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there... if you don't want to actually call the functions when you load them into the dict, then don't.

```
etl_func_dict["Update"] = UpdateFunc
etl_func_dict["Append"] = AppendFunc
etl_func_dict["Recreate"] = RecreateFunc
```

Leaving off the parens stores a reference to the functions without actually calling them. Just be sure to call the function when you want to. For example:

```
s = etl_func_dict[name]()
```

Comment: Also @HelpfulHound, know that this technique works for any `lambda` or built-in function.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple like that. Thank you! Marked as answer.